# Let $V$ be a vector space such that $\dim V=n$ and let $B\subseteq V$ be a set such that $|B|>n$. Why is it that $B$ is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ such that $\dim V=n$ and let $B\subseteq V$ be a set such that $|B|>n$. Why is it that $B$ is linearly dependent?

---

Definition of (finite) dimension:
We say that a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$ has a dimension of $n$ if there si a basis $B\subseteq V$ with $|B|=n$. We say that $n=\dim V$.

Comment: What is your definition of the dimension of a vector space?

Comment: I just added it to the body of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B$ is linearly independent, then it is a basis for $\text{span}(B)$, so $\dim(\text{span}(B)) > n$. But $\text{span}(B)$ is a subspace of $V$ (because $B$ is a subset of $V$), so $\dim(\text{span}(B)) \le \dim V = n$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Since the dimension $\dim V = n$ of $V$ over $\mathbb{K}$ is defined as the cardinality of any basis $B \subset V$ for $V$, and this number is invariant of choice of basis, any set of greater than $n$ vectors cannot be a linearly independent as the basis is both maximally linearly independent and also spanning. So any set $B \subset V$ such that $|B| > n$ cannot be linearly independent.